# SSIS: Execute SQL task fails when trying to call one stored procedure from another

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am running a Execute SQL task in which I am storing a variable which calls a procedure:

```
exec load_storedproc1 parameter1, parameter2
```

Now this stored procedure has a statement in the end which calls another stored procedure:

```
exec load_storedproc2 parameter1, parameter2
```

The parameters which are supposed to be passed for both the stored procedures are the same.

When I execute the SQL task, it calls the first stored procedure which executes successfully but when it reaches the end statement of it, which is to call the storedproc2, it fails with the error message:

> Error: Invalid column name 'column1'.
>   Error: Invalid column name 'column2'.
>   Error: Invalid column name 'column3'.

`column1, column2, column3` are columns from the table used in storedproc2.

I feel somehow the Execute SQL task is not able to call the `storedproc2` and it keeps failing. I am using `dbname.schemaname.tablename` everywhere in  `storedproc2`.

Comment: Show us some code. Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, I am using SQL server                                                                     
                                                                                                                
Create Procedure [dbo].[storedproc1]

(parameter1 datetime,
parameter2 Varchar(10))

as 

begin

--procedure1 code--


exec [DWIKNOW].[dbo].[storedproc2] @parameter1,@parameter2  -- this statement is where the SQL task fails


end
go

Comment: Please edit your question and put the code in there. You're going to need to include the code inside the second stored procedure. We can't debug code without seeing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my issue. When we are calling one stored procedure from another stored procedure, in case we are using temp tables, the names of all the temp tables in both the stored procedure should be different as the SQL task will treat both as a single session.

I was using temp tables in the stored procedures and few of the names across both the stored procedures were same. After changing them, its working fine now.